Best puzzles of 2024 Q3 (July - September)?
This question is part of the best-puzzle award series


What are your nominations for the best puzzles, here on Puzzling.SE, of the third quarter (July/August/September) 2024?


Suggested guidelines for nomination:

Nominate each individual puzzle in a separate answer, so they can be upvoted/downvoted separately.

No more than 3 nominations per person.

Don't nominate your own puzzles.

Before you nominate a puzzle, check to see if someone else has already nominated it. If they have, then add to that nomination as a comment (or edit it) instead of nominating the same puzzle again.

In your nomination, explain what it is that (in your opinion) makes the nominated puzzle such a good one.



Some lists to help jog your memory (your nomination doesn't have to be from these lists):

Algorithmically selected "best of":

Popular puzzles, both in score and in vote to view ratio, from 2024 Q3
Well received puzzles you may have missed from 2024 Q3

Best by votes/views:

Questions with the most votes from 2024 Q3
Questions with the most views from 2024 Q3
Questions with the highest-voted answers from 2024 Q3



Meta-meta issues:
Q: Is this kind of thing allowed on SE?
A: Yes, Photography SE and Sci-Fi & Fantasy SE do something very similar.
Q: What's the point?
A1: To highlight and encourage good practice in a way that goes beyond upvotes.
A2: To work towards building a 'hall of fame' of some of the best puzzles on the site (perhaps to reside on a future puzzling.SE blog) - think of it as our 'greatest hits album'.
A3: To prompt members to put forward their own reflections on what makes a high-quality puzzle.

World's smallest Sudoku! by Beastly Gerbil
This one snuck in just under the deadline, but it immediately stood out to me as something special.
The puzzle is presented with some flavor text and a question meant to clarify the answer, but at the end of the day, the puzzle is entirely encoded within a single, 3-pixel-by-3-pixel image, just 216 bits of data. Within that miniscule framework, Beastly Gerbil was able to hide enough information to create a sudoku puzzle that was not only solvable, but revealed an additional sub-puzzle inside it, and after all that, managed to have everything resolve into a thematic final answer.
This is one of those puzzles where as I was solving it, my jaw just kept inching closer and closer to the floor as I realized how it was all coming together. The fact that such a feat of puzzle engineering is even possible is remarkable on its own, but that it was executed so smoothly and brilliantly makes it more than worthy of a spot on this list.
